# GCF HTTP Request, Error: quota exceeded (CPU allocation in function invocations : per day)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am currently working with Firebase Cloud Functions, doing an HTTP Request through Functions. The HTTP request is being done by a 3G Module, and I need to always read a value change in the Database.

This system is to be used in an application that, as soon as there is a change in the DB, I should notify the 3G module, so currently I am doing it with an HTTP request.

```
exports.moduleRequest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 var change  = admin.database().ref('/userInfo');
 ////Once there is a change in  any userInfo child, do something
 change.once('child_changed', (snapshot) =>{
   res.send(snapshot.val());
 });
});
```

This is working perfectly fine, the problem is that I leave the HTTP request open until there is a change in the DB, so this is consuming the quota provided from Firebase in about 60 minutes.

```
Error: quota exceeded (CPU allocation in function invocations : per day); 
check and increase your quota at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-
admin/quotas?project=pass-
e098f&service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&usage=ALL. Function killed.
```

Do you know if there is another  approach to get this system working?

Comment: Cloud Functions are not well-suited to long-lived HTTP requests like long-polling. Every second the function is running is charging you for memory/CPU time. I'd recommend either running different infrastructure (e.g. App Engine Flex or Container Engine) or figuring out a way to architect your app so it doesn't need long-open HTTP connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest and best way to solve my issue is to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/), as it let me do streaming through a HTTP GET request. It uses my SIMCOM SIM5320 3G module as a client, and the server then sends an event with the database update at the requested path.